# angular7 - input type=checkbox taking long time to bind - Performance issue

Tags: angular, performance, checkbox

Performance Issue - I am trying to load users list in checkbox control in Angular7 application. Users data contains around 15000 records, this checkbox binding it takes 20 seconds. I tried with `<mat-checkbox>` and input type checkbox. Is there any other option to bind all the data quickly in this checkbox control?

code snippet.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="user.IsChecked" name="{{user.Id}}" value="{{user.Id}}"
      (change)="onChange(user.IsChecked, user.Id)" />
    {{user.Name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what onChange method do? Please share code rather than image

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by * generator. However you can use trackBy as well.

Comment: Hi! Please paste the code _as text,_ not images of code. They can't be easily searched, or copied into answers.

Answer (score 0):

try use trackByIndex

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users; trackBy: trackByMethod">
    ...
</li>

trackByMethod(index:number, el:any): number {
 return el.Id;
}
```

Or use a paginator or a filter in select (15000 record is much more to show it at time)